# Send a mail using Javascript without going through Outlook

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is it possible to Send a mail using Javascript without going through Outlook

Comment: I think u have to provide more info, do u want to send mail user's account who visit ur website?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.
Long answer: if you use a server-side component that you access asynchronously, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible. You can't send a mail using JavaScript without user intervertion.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot purely use javascript to send e-mail without outlook, your javascript will need to interact with a server side language e.g. asp.net / php etc.

Or there are numerous free services which allow you to send your e-mail via their server-side, such as http://allforms.mailjol.net/